# Django session variable value lost after refreshing a page

Tags: python, django, session

In my views i am trying to save some information with Django sessions, so in my views.py i have this:

```
def shop_product(request, slug):
    tshirt = Tshirt.objects.get(slug=slug)

    request.session['items'] = []  
    product = {}

    if(request.GET.get('add')):
        product['name'] = tshirt.title
        product['price'] = tshirt.price_reg
        request.session['items'].append(product)
        request.session.modified = True


    if(request.GET.get('clear')):
        request.session['items'][:] = []
        request.session.modified = True


    context = {'items' : request.session['items']}


    return render(request, 'shop/shop_product.html', context)
```

I would like that 'items' array contains and adds 'product' that is a dict and also be available anywhere on the web site (like other views e.g.shopping_cart) when i refresh the page

The problem is that when I'm on the same page/view (just described above) when I do a refresh to the page I have problems retrieving 'items'. also if I go to a different page and then come back to the original page the values in 'items' are gone. Also the value is not available on any other page/view.

my template/html looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="add" name="add">
    <input type="submit" value="CLEAR" class="clr" name="clear">
</form>
```

Comment: You explicitly clear items at the start of the function. I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: yes, that is a mistake i made, thanks Daniel for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code :

```
def shop_product(request, slug):
    tshirt = Tshirt.objects.get(slug=slug)
    product = {}

    if(request.GET.get('add') and request.GET.get('add')=='add'):
        product['name'] = tshirt.title
        product['price'] = tshirt.price_reg
        request.session['items'].append(product)
        request.session.modified = True


    if(request.GET.get('clear') and request.GET.get('add')=='clear' ):
        request.session['items'] = []
        request.session.modified = True


    context = {'items' : request.session['items']}


    return render(request, 'shop/shop_product.html', context)
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="add" class="add" name="add">
    <input type="submit" value="clear" class="clr" name="clear">
</form>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer Yogesh, it saves the Tshirt name and Tshirt price, and the items array is persistent, after refreshing the page ang going to http://localhost:8000/cart/ it contains  all the dictionaries with Tshirt price and Tshirt name :)
I think the 'clear' button is not emptying 'items' array, but that is ok, i think i can fix it, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Chnage This Line : From if(request.GET.get('clear') and request.GET.get('add')=='clear' ): To if(request.GET.get('clear') and request.GET.get('clear')=='clear' ):

Comment: Hi Yogesh do you have any idea what is happening here with the request.session['items'] ... 
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'items'   context = {'shirt_list': shirt_list, 'slug':slug, 'shlist' : shlist,
               'tshirt' : tshirt, 'productArray' : request.session['items']}

Comment: Use  request.session.get('items').